# EmailMessageRelation with missing RelationObjectType and RelationId fields

Tags: servicecloud, emailmessage

I'm trying to get author ID of an `EmailMessage` written by an agent in a `Case`.

As far as I understand it should be available in the linked `EmailMessageRelation` with `RelationType = 'FromAddress'`. However when I query `EmailMessageRelation` - I get `null` values for `RelationObjectType` and `RelationId` fields. I would expect `RelationObjectType` to be populated with `'User'` and `RelationId` with the `User.Id` of the author.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something in Salesforce setup?

I'm using a developer Salesforce account. `Email-to-Case` is configured. `Enhanced Email` was enabled by default.

The flow looks like this:

- Send an email to the routing address configured in `Email-to-Case`
- `Case` is automatically generated
- Write a reply Email from Salesforce